# Proving $\cos (z)$ is real for real values of $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given the definition of cos function through the exponential function, how can we prove rigorously that for real values of $z$  $$\cos(z)=\operatorname{Re}(\exp(iz))$$?

Comment: How about looking at the power series of $\cos z$?

Comment: Prove first that $\mathrm{Re}(z) = (z + \overline{z})/2$ for any complex number $z$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $\overline{e^z} =e^{\overline{z}}$. Hence for $z\in \mathbb{R}$, $$\text{cos}(z) = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2} = \frac{e^{iz}+e^{\overline{iz}}}{2} = \frac{e^{iz}+\overline{e^{iz}}}{2} = \text{Re}(e^{iz})$$