# All values of z for which cos(z) has real values

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find all values of z for which $\cos(z)$ has real values.

My approach: By definition $\cos(z)= 0.5(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$

Subbing in $z=x+iy$, $\cos(z)=0.5(e^{ix}e^{-y}+e^{-ix}e^{y})$

Therefore $\cos(z)$ is only real when $x=0, i$ and $-1$.

Is this correct?

Comment: check this previous question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237646/proving-cos-z-is-real-for-real-values-of-z

Comment: should it not include all the reals at least?

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $\cos(x+iy) = \cos(x) \cosh(y) - i \sin(x) \sinh(y)$.  When is the imaginary part $0$?

Comment: When x= n*pi or y=(n*pi)i , where n is an integer?

Comment: Yes for the $x$, no for the $y$.  We're talking about real $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So when x=n*pi and y=0?  Thanks for your help